CommonName SSL_Self_Signed_Fallback and subject name does not match host name
I am trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server using:
sqlcmd -S server.example.com\\instance_name,1433 -U $MSSQL_USER -P $MSSQL_PASSWORD -d mydatabase

I keep getting this error:

Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server : SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:self-signed certificate]

Therefore I got the certificate of the SQL Server using:
nmap -v --script=ssl-cert -p 1433 server.example.com

(see here: OpenSSL: Fetching SQL Server public certificate)
which returned an answer in the form of:
1433/tcp open  ms-sql-s
| ssl-cert: Subject: commonName=SSL_Self_Signed_Fallback
| Issuer: commonName=SSL_Self_Signed_Fallback
| Public Key type: rsa
| Public Key bits: 2048
| Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
| Not valid before: 2024-06-16T10:20:00
| Not valid after:  2054-06-16T10:20:00
| MD5:   <somethinghere>
| SHA-1: c3aa8d4443a5e8f6a9f6cbaedc888d9b28d77b49
| -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

After doing this and adding the certificates to trust certificates in my client (debian 12)
Using
cp mycert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
update-ca-certificates

Now I am facing this error:

Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server : SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:subject name does not match host name].

Is this because the person who self-signed the certificate did not add the correct CN as server.example.com and SSL is expecting that in the CN of the certificate there should be server.example.com and therefore there is nothing else I can do?
Thanks a lot!
Edit: I am aware that adding a -C in the command will trust the certificate by default, but I don't want that. I want to identify that certificate as trusted. I think like this I am avoiding man-in-the-middle attacks, if I am not wrong.

there's an command line switch to trustservercertificate when connecting with sqlcmd, it should be easy to find in the docs

Is this because the person who self-signed the certificate did not add the correct CN... no, it's because SQL Server always installs with a self-signed certificate. It's up to the DBA to acquire a replacement certificate from their Organizational CA, or a public CA, that has the correct host name and/or IP addresses in its CN and/or Subject Alternative Names.

Is this because the person who self-signed the certificate did not add the correct CN as server.example.com and SSL is expecting that in the CN of the certificate there should be server.example.com and therefore there is nothing else I can do Possibly, but you should also be looking in the subject alternative names extension for the hostnames/ip addresses that the certificate contains.

"I am aware that adding a -C in the command will trust the certificate by default, but I don't want that. I want to identify that certificate as trusted." then you need to get/buy and install a proper certificate signed by a public or private CA that is a trusted root on your machine.
